# Can't access web-page started by webpack-dev-server on vagrant

Tags: webpack, vagrant, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

Starting with React and Flux architecture but met some infrastucture troubles.

I can't access the web-page started by webpack-dev-server on the vagrant box (scotch-box). The command starts the application on localhost:3002, my vagrant box has an IP (192.168.33.10) address in Windows host machine and I can access it. But when I trying to access 192.168.33.10:3002 I'm getting the error: 
"*Cant get access to the page....*"

I checked that I have access to page from the vagrant box console `curl http://localhost:3002`.

Does anyone have any ideas why that happens?

I'm also using the babel and presets for es2015 and react.

Here is the webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js/main.js",
    output: {
        path: "./dist",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3002,
        contentBase: "./dist"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel",
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "flux-jenezis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Flux realisatoin usign egghead guide",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "flux",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "jenezis",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0"
  }
}
```

**UPD**: I can access different applications started by node server, and they accessable by `192.168.33.10:3002`

**UPD2:** made network diagnostic using windows default tools, and the diagnose was: "*Remote Device Won't Accept Connection*"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the solution. By default `webpack-dev-server` runs the application on `localhost:<port>`. To change it you can run the `webpack-dev-server` using this command (by passing the --host option):

`webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --hot --host 0.0.0.0`

`0.0.0.0` binds to all hosts.

I changed my `package.json` and now it's look like:

```
{
  "name": "flux-jenezis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Flux realisatoin usign egghead guide",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "flux",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "jenezis",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {    
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: With Webpack 2+ (^2.4.3) there's a good chance you'll get `Invalid Host header` if you're running with an aliased host (for example in virtualbox). You'll want to add `--public <your_host>:<port>` as well.

Comment: @Kristoffer as for now, I would prefer Docker container instead

Answer (score 2):

For those who may still have this problem, like I did, the issue for me was with the **port-forwarding**. My Virtualbox VM is a linux VM with an apache web server on it. I use Vagrant to easily spin up my VM with a config file, Vagrant calls these a 'Vagrantfile'. In the 'Vagrantfile' you can specify ports you want forwarded between the guest machine (your VM) and the host machine (your actual OS).

This looks something like this:

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000`

When the VM spins up , that port(s) will now be accessible from your guest machine on your host machine. In other words, if your webpack config looks like this:

```
devServer: {
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3000
}
```

You should now be able to visit `http://0.0.0.0:3000` from your browser on your host machine.

Note: If you're using Virtualbox but not Vagrant and you still need help with port-forward, visit this article for some good tips: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/08/fix-webpack-watch-virtualbox/